# Best practice to setup a development environment with source control,vscode and sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, environment

i have been working on the traditional way of developing within salesforce using Force.comIDE / aside.io / developer console. i want to move to a more robust way of writing code using a source control(GIT?), VSCode, scratch orgs and sandboxes.

Here is how i think i want to go ( correct me if i am wrong )

1. setup a sandbox for final QA
2. Pull in all latest metadata into SB
3. pull everything from SB into version control( need help setting this up)
4. Each user will pull it from version control and work on his branch or scratch org and commit it back once they finish the work. ( Not worked too much with version control so any input would be welcome)
5. Then push it from source control into Sandbox for QA
6. Then move it to production

Is there a better way to do it? Does any one have reference to articles which can help set it up

Answer (score 3):

Your approach looks correct to me AFAIK. Now we can use SFDX with development orgs as well so if you want you can skip the scratch org part else everythings look good.

I suggest you check this trail. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/sfdx_get_started In this trail Salesforce shared step by steps of how we can setup the SFDX with existing org and move our code to version control and Continuous Integration.

I also suggest you to check the SFDX considerations with scratch org limitation to make your decision.

Here are some links for your reference.

[Scratch Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm)
[Limitations for Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_considerations.htm)
[SFDX: Use With Non Scratch Org](https://newstechnologystuff.com/2018/10/27/sfdx-use-with-non-scratch-org/)